# Does local system cohomology come equiped with a mixed hodge structure?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, hodge-theory

Let $X$ be a quasi-projective variety over $\mathbb{C}$, and let $\mathcal{L}$ be a rank one $\mathbb{C}$ local system on $X$. Does $H^*(X,\mathcal{L})$ come with some mixed hodge structure in general?

Comment: If you only have a $\mathbb{C}$-local system, you cannot expect to have a mixed Hodge structure since the cohomology has no rational structure. (It seems likely though that there should be a natural $\mathbb{C}$-MHS, but I do not know any reference for this.)

Comment: @ulrich I get your point about the rational structure. Can you explain what you mean by a $\mathbb{C}$-MHS?

Comment: Take a look at my old paper "Geometry of cohomology support loci I" for an explanation of what a $\mathbb{C}$-MHS is, and how  you get one on the  cohomology of  $\mathcal{L}$ (which needs to be unitary). The arXiv version is https://arxiv.org/pdf/alg-geom/9612006.pdf